# How can WPF TranslateTransform be used with Margin to move an image to the correct location

Tags: c#, wpf, image, coordinates

I have a WPF `Image` on a 1x1 grid that I'm trying to move to a new location.  I'm using the following code:

```
public void AnimateImage(int seatNum, int cardNum)
{
   // This method animates dealing a cardback image to the specified seat.
   //
   Point[][,] Margins;
   Margins = CardMargins; // CardMargins contains the positions to where the cards should end up after being moved.
   Image CardbackImage1 = CardbackImages[seatNum, cardNum];
   // Specify the starting position of the image.
   CardbackImage1.Margin = new Thickness(DealerStartX, DealerStartY, 0, 0);
   CardsGrid.Children.Insert(seatNum, CardbackImage1);
   // Note that if instead of specifying the starting point, the to-point is specified instead,
   // and a return inserted at this point - it displays the card in the correct location.
   TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
   CardbackImage1.RenderTransform = trans;
   double ToPosX = Margins[NumSeats][seatNum, cardNum].X;
   double ToPosY = Margins[NumSeats][seatNum, cardNum].Y;
   // DoubleAnimation CardsAnimX = new DoubleAnimation(DealerStartX, 65, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DealAnimateTime));
   DoubleAnimation CardsAnimX = new DoubleAnimation(DealerStartX, ToPosX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DealAnimateTime));
   // DoubleAnimation CardsAnimY = new DoubleAnimation(DealerStartY, DealerStartY - 50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DealAnimateTime));
   DoubleAnimation CardsAnimY = new DoubleAnimation(DealerStartY, ToPosY, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DealAnimateTime));
   trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, CardsAnimX);
   trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, CardsAnimY);
}
```

The `CardMargins` array is used to hold the locations of where the card should end up.  The card animates, but The problem is that the card is not ending up in the proper location.  I have verified that the values inside of the `CardMargins` array are correct along with the indexes to the array.  I suspect that the `TranslateTransform` method is either using a different type of coordinates or maybe a different coordinate system.

Can margin be used as an animation property, and if so does any type of transformation need to be used in order for it to be used with `TranslateTransform`?  Is there a better way of animating an image without using margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simpler to animate the `Margin` property itself using `ThicknessAnimation`

Example:

```
ThicknessAnimation CardAni = new ThicknessAnimation(StartMargin, EndMargin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DealAnimateTime));
CardbackImage1.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, CardAni);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Problem solved.  The cards end up in the right spot with your code suggestion.